# generic return type for dl'ed functions

Tags: c, dynamic-loading

Hi Im loading functions dynamically and executing them. I want be able to define a generic return type so that compiler can clean up the stack properly. Currently its printing gibberish for version string.

How can I make the following code work?

```
// gcc -o test test.c -ldl

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef union  { int i; double d; float f; char *p;} anytype; 

int main()
{
  anytype ver2;

  anytype (*f)();

    void *handle = dlopen("libz.so.1", RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
    f = dlsym(handle,"zlibVersion");
    //const char * zlibVersion (void);
    ver2=f();
    printf("zlib version %s\n", ver2.p);
    dlclose(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the function pointer type that exactly matches the function being called. In this case, define `f` as `const char* (*f)(void)`. Though your code should be working as is, there's no reason to do it the way you did.

Comment: @nm sure there is a reason! this is kinda how Visual C Edit-and-Continue works.

Comment: I'm sure Visual C Edit-and-Continue has nothing to do with `dlopen` and `RTLD_GOLBAL` whatsoever. Even if some code in Visual C++ resembles what you have written, this means absolutely nothing to anyone who programs outside of that environment, and probably to those who work within it too.

Comment: @nm thanks for contributing nothing.

Comment: If you don't understand something, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use a `union` to substitute for a return value of an unknown type. On architectures which have floating point registers, a floating point return value is returned in a floating point register, while an integer or pointer return value is returned in a general purpose register. Usually, if the return value is a union or struct, the caller must provide a first argument pointing to a storage area (of the correct size) which the callee will fill in with the return value. (There are lots of variations. It's completely dependent on the platform ABI; what I described is (part of) the i386 ABI.)

So you really need to know the signature of the function in order to call it.